# Clicking on a div and saving its value to use with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have been having some problems with some code. 
So I'm developing a website that accesses a mysql database and creates a number of divs accordingly to the number of specialties that are on the database.

```
    <div id="services_panel">
        <?php foreach ($specialties as $especialidade_id => $especialidade) { ?>
            <div class="service_div" onclick ="highlightLink(this); $('#content_div').show();" value="<?php echo $especialidade_id; ?>"><?php echo $especialidade; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content_div""/>
```

Now what I wanted to do was set the value of the content div to the value of $especialidade of the div that was clicked, but since javascript runs clientside and php runs server side, I know that I can't do it on onclick()

I'd really hope you guys could help me with this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have that information when PHP is parsed, use PHP to write a Javascript function that will perform this action upon the click event.

Comment: can you show me how you'd do that? I'm failing hard at trying to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `onclick()` inline you could do

```
onclick ="highlightLink(this); $('#content_div').show().html(this.innerHTML);"
```

or if you bind it separately using `.on()` and `'click'`

```
$(function(){
    $('.service_div').on('click',function(){
       $('#content_div').show().html($(this).html()); 
    });
});
```